# What is the performance cost of maintaining a live HTMLCollection?

Tags: javascript, performance, htmlcollection

A piece of my front-end JS code is depending on a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of several thousand DOM nodes. Since it is live, it updates automatically as the DOM is updated.

Is this the same as re-running the`document.getElementsByClassName` call every single time I modify the DOM, or is there a performance optimization under the hood?

Comment: It depends. Murphy says that if you really need the optimization then it won't be available in the deployed environment. If you don't need it then it will be available.

Comment: https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2010/09/28/why-is-getelementsbytagname-faster-that-queryselectorall/

Comment: @skyboyer That article is a little misleading. *Creating* a live NodeList is really fast, because the overhead of finding the DOM elements is deferred until the elements are accessed.

Comment: @Barmar article states the same: "Live NodeList objects can be created and returned faster by the browser because they don’t have to have all of the information up front while static NodeLists need to have all of their data from the start. "

Comment: @skyboyer Right, they can be created faster, but the first access will be slower by the same amount. There's no free lunch.

Answer (score 5):

[This blog post](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2010/09/28/why-is-getelementsbytagname-faster-that-queryselectorall/) explains a little of the difference between static and live `NodeLists`, and mentions how live collections are implemented.

A live collection doesn't access the DOM until you access its elements. At that time it creates the actual collection and caches it. There's no overhead to future accesses if the DOM doesn't change.

Changing the DOM shouldn't cause an immediate update to any collections. Rather, it should just invalidate their caches. The next time you access one of the collections, it will be regenerated.

So if you create a live collection and access it infrequently compared to DOM modifications, there should be relatively little overhead. The worst case is if you loop over a live collection and modify the DOM during the loop -- each iteration will have to update the collection.

It's possible that there may be additional optimizations that could mitigate this. For some types of live collections, the JavaScript engine may be able to tell whether a particular DOM modification could affect it; if not, it doesn't have to invalidate the collection. For instance, a collection created with `document.getElementsByClassName()` would not be affected by a modification that doesn't add or remove the specified class anywhere. However, if you do something like delete an element, it would have to check whether the class appeared anywhere in the subtree headed by that element, so it's not obvious that this would really be better than just invalidating the caches.